# PTIJ: Must I really increase my joy?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The mishnah teaches that when it is Adar, we all increase our joy.

> משנכנס אדר מרבים בשמחה

However, I recently saw another Mishnah (Menachot 13;11) which completely contradicts this by saying that some must increase and some must decrease.

> אחד המרבה ואחד הממעיט

Which is it, and who does what?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: that's an argument based in hemisphere. In Australia, it is 9 Av right now. So while one side of the earth increases, the other side maintains orbital balance by decreasing. Because science.

Comment: Where is the 2nd Mishnah located?

Comment: @rosends Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @DonielF I don't like to give heavily scientific answers to religiously based questions.

Comment: @rosends In the interest of PTIJ I think you can go against your usual practice. Consider it your dose of Mishloach Minus.

Comment: See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100942/ptij-at-the-passover-seder-is-one-allowed-to-speak-more-than-once-during-maggi/100954#100954) for the explanation of אחד המרבה.

Answer (score 2):

The two Mishnayot are not contradictory.

The 1st one refers to a normal year that has just one Adar. On such years, you increase your joy. You celebrate Purim as one means to increase the joy.

The second Mishnah refers to leap years. During one Adar, you increase your joy by celebrating a "Full" Purim as you do in non-leap years. During the other Adar you decrease your joy by celebrating a "Little" Purim known as פורים קטן.